# Converting numbers from cell arrays to vector matrix

Tags: matlab

The code below sorts the cell array in descending order using column 2, I will like to extract the numbers in the cell array in column 4 and convert them to a matrix.

```
data = cell (9,4);

col1 = ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I'];
col2 = [-45 -90 -50 -54 -70 -57 -75 -64 -23];    
col3 = [{'1,1'},{'1,5'},{'3,9'},{'4,2'},{'4,6'},{'6,2'},{'7,6'},{'6,9'},{'9,9'}];    
col4 = [{2 3 4 5 8},{1 3 4 5 8},{1 2 5 7 8},{1 2 3 6 7},{3 4 7 8},{2 4 8 9},{2 4 5 9},{4 5 7 9},{2 6 7 8}];

for i = 1:length(data)    
    data{i,1} = col1(i);    
    data{i,2} = col2(i);    
    data{i,3} = col3(i);    
    data{i,4} = col4(i);
end    
[trash, idx] = sort([data{:,2}], 'descend');    
newData = data(idx,:)
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: _"I will like to extract the numbers in the cell array in column 4 and convert them to a 9x1 matrix."_. Good luck =) What do you mean by "extract the numbers" anyway? Take the sum of each block? I'll retract my downvote if you explain it better =)

Comment: The numbers in column 4 are in cell array format. I will to convert the numbers to vectors. I will like to have something like: [0 2 6 7 8; 2 3 4 5 8; .....;1 3 4 5 8]. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use cell arrays throughout. Your code above doesn't do what you think it does. Here is a corrected version.

```
data = cell (9,4);

col1 = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'};
col2 = {-45, -90, -50, -54, -70, -57, -75, -64, -23};    
col3 = {'1,1', '1,5', '3,9', '4,2', '4,6', '6,2', '7,6', '6,9', '9,9'};    %%%
col4 = {[2 3 4 5 8],[1 3 4 5 8],[1 2 5 7 8],[1 2 3 6 7],[3 4 7 8],[2 4 8 9],[2 4 5 9],[4 5 7 9],[2 6 7 8]}; %%%

for i = 1:length(data)    
    data{i,1} = col1{i};    
    data{i,2} = col2{i};    
    data{i,3} = col3{i}; %%%    
    data{i,4} = col4{i}; %%%
end    
[~, idx] = sort([data{:,2}], 'descend');    %%%
newData = data(idx,:)
```

Now, as for "extracting to a matrix", **if** all rows contained the same number of elements, you could obtain this like so: `[newData{:,4}]`. But, as it stands now, you can't, because some rows have 4 elements, and some 5. So you need to decide whether you want to add zeros left or right etc to make them of equal size.

Also, it's not clear why you say `9x1`. If your intention is to perform an operation on these rows such that they return a single value, you have not made this clear here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and modification of the code. As you rightly pointed out, the 9x1 matrix was in error and misleading. Also, as you noted, some rows have 4 numbers while some have 5, i will like to add zero(s) to the left side to make them equal. Therefore, for this particular code, the output will be a 9x5 matrix. Thanks

Comment: good. look at the `padarray` function, and use it to pad matrices if they are of shorter length